# Loop through rows in Google Spreadsheets and grouping/counting items

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script, count, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet with these columns:

```
| Id|   User  | Voucher         |     Store ID |
| 0 |   User1 | Welcome Voucher |     42       |
| 1 |   User2 | Other Voucher   |     42       |
| 2 |   User3 | Welcome Voucher |     42       |
| 3 |   User2 | Other Voucher   |     42       |
| 4 |   User2 | Other Voucher   |     12       |
```

A store can have different vouchers. I want to loop through this spreadsheet and count the vouchers with the same name and storeID 42. What is the best way to achieve this? Do I have to group them and then count? Or do I have to push them to different arrays and then count length?

```
 $.getJSON(getVouchersUrl, function(data) {
      $.each(data, function (index, value) {
         // count same 
     });
 });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your question isn't clear, please edit it to help future readers. Specifics: Are your trying to get the answer _in Google Sheets_, or are you using the spreadsheet as a database? Where is the jquery code snippet running, within a google apps script container or external? Why google-apps-script tag?

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick workaround for my question but I'm sure it's not the most efficient way. If there is someone who can simplify my code it would be awesome!

```
$.getJSON(getVouchersUrl, function(data) {
     $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        obj[value[2]] = (obj[value[2]] || 0) + 1;
     });

     for (var vouchers in obj) {
        var number = obj[vouchers]
        $('.voucherList').append("<li class='list-group-item'><span class='badge'>"+number+"</span>" + vouchers + "</li>"); 
     }

     $('.loaderIcon').hide();
     $('.voucherStats').show();
     $('.amountVouchers').animateNumber({ number: numberOfVouchers });

});
```

Comment: there are built in spreadsheet functions for doing this kind of thing. you should not need a script.

Comment: When you have working code, and are looking for recommendations for improvement, you can post another question here on SO, or (better yet) post on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).